# How to add a part of code to the ternary operator using javascript and react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have code like below,

```
const variableType = 'INTEGER';
const editedValue = 100;
const defaultValue = 4;
return (
    isOpen ? (
        <span>something</span>
    ) : (
        <>
            {(variableType ?? '').toUpperCase() === 'BOOLEAN'
                ? capitalize(editedValue ?? '')
                : {editedValue}
        </>
    );
```

Now i want to add is when this variableType is not boolean and editedValue is not same as defaultValue i want to show an icon along with editedValue

if variableType is not boolean and edited Value is same as defaultValue i want to just show editedValue.

i have tried something like so,

```
return (
    isOpen ? (
        <span>something</span>
    ) : (
        <>
            {(variableType ?? '').toUpperCase() === 'BOOLEAN'
                ? capitalize(editedValue ?? '')
                : {editedValue !== defaultValue && (
                    <Icon />
                  }
                  {editedValue}
        </>
    );
```

But the above doesnt seem right syntatically.

how can i change the above ternary operator to satisfy above condition and show icon. could someone help me with this. i am new to using ternary operator. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key here is understanding what parts are in JSX elements and what parts aren't. When you're in an element or fragment, you're in a JSX element and you use `{...}` to insert values or code. When you're inside `{...}`, you're **not** in a JSX expression.

I think you probably want:

```
return (
    isOpen ? (
        <span>something</span>
    ) : (
        (variableType ?? '').toUpperCase() === 'BOOLEAN'
            ? capitalize(editedValue ?? '')
            : <>
                {editedValue !== defaultValue && <Icon />}
                {editedValue}
              </>
    );
```

....but I would suggest you break that up to make it easier to read and maintain. For instance:

```
if (isOpen) {
    return <span>something</span>;
}
if ((variableType ?? '').toUpperCase() === 'BOOLEAN') {
    return capitalize(editedValue ?? '');
}
return <>
    {editedValue !== defaultValue && <Icon />}
    {editedValue}
</>;
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
  if (isOpen) return <span>something</span>

  return (
    <>
      {(variableType ?? '').toUpperCase() === 'BOOLEAN'
        ? capitalize(editedValue ?? '')
        : <>
          {editedValue !== defaultValue && <Icon />}
          {editedValue}
        </>
      }
    </>
  )
```