# Why react map function is not working properly?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json

when I  use the map in react, do I get an unexpected token error?

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

export default function ApiHook() {
  const [employees, setEmployees] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios
      .get("http://dummy.restapiexample.com/api/v1/employees")
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        setEmployees(response.data);
      })
      .catch((e) => console.log(e));
  }, []);
  return (
      {employees.map((employee) => {
        return <p>{employee.employee_name}</p>;
      })}
  );
}
```

Comment: You should add `map` inside `React.Fragment` or `<> ... </>`

Comment: It's because you've used a JSX expression (`{...}`) where you're not in a JSX context, you're just in normal JavaScript context. Simply remove the `{` and `}` from around the `map` call and return the array directly. Or, alternatively, wrap the array in a fragment or similar, but there's no need unless you have some other reason to do that.

Comment: So either `return employees.map((employee) => { return <p>{employee.employee_name}</p>; });` or `return (<>{employees.map((employee) => { return <p>{employee.employee_name}</p>; })} </>);` (Side note: The `map` callback can be just `.map(employee => <p>{employee.employee_name}</p>)` or even `.map(({employee_name}) => <p>{employee_name}</p>)`)

Comment: Voted to close as typo.

Comment: At least related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69583384/how-to-add-a-part-of-code-to-the-ternary-operator-using-javascript-and-react

Answer (score 1):

You have to wrap with a fragment. Because you have to return only one element.

```
 return (
    <>
      {employees.map((employee) => {
        return <p>{employee.employee_name}</p>;
      })}
    </>
  );
```

Comment: I think this is the right answere. But it would be handy to adress the problem and not just post the correct code. I think the problem is, that the return function needs a single react element to be passed as parameter and the map function returns an array of react elements. So to solve this op can wrap the array in an empty react element (<></>) how its done in your code

Comment: @Olli - This is **one** right way to code it (though as you say, not really an answer if there's zero explanation). The other would be to just return the array. It's perfectly valid to return an array from a component function (or `class` component `render` function).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Yes you are right. Returning an array is valid too. It's just not valid int this case because of the { } (like you wrote in your comment on the qustion itself). I didn't know this. But i dont understand why this question got closed. I don't think this is should be evaluated as a typo. To me this issue seems more likly to arise from the lack of knowledge of the "context switching" inside of the jsx part. (which i also didn't know)

Comment: @Olli - Yeah, very borderline call in my view, but there will also be multiple duplicates (if only we could find them amongst all the questions!). :-) Like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69583384/how-to-add-a-part-of-code-to-the-ternary-operator-using-javascript-and-react).